# Syncfusion : How to install only Grid component from Syncfusion for Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, datagrid, syncfusion

I am working on a Web App which Uses Syncfusion grid to display tabular Data.
My App is Webpack based (not CLI). I have followed [Getting Started with Webpack](https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/gettingstarted/getting-started-webpack) guide from Syncfusion website and integrated   into my APP.

The grid is showing up as it's supposed to be. 
The problem is, when I compile the code , the bundle size is about 19MB and almost 13MB is occupied by Syncfusion.

The help I wanted is can anybody please tell me how to install only grid component from syncfusion library? I did't found any solution which helps me to do so.

**Package json :** 
`{
    ...........
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "syncfusion-javascript": "~15.4.21",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2"
    .......,
}`

**Included in Vendor.ts :**

```
import '../../node_modules/syncfusion-javascript/Content/ej/web/material/ej.web.all.min.css';
import '../../node_modules/syncfusion-javascript/Content/ej/web/responsive-css/ej.responsive.css';
```

Imported in Module.ts file :

```
import { EJAngular2Module } from 'ej-angular2'; 
imports: [
    ......
    EJAngular2Module.forRoot(),
   ........
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the required components alone in `Angular` application using the below code snippet instead of `EJAngular2Module` importing, which includes the required modules and their corresponding source alone into `Angular` application build.

```
import { EJ_GRID_COMPONENTS } from 'ej-angular2/src/ej/grid.component';
```

We discussed this information in the following article: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7861/importing-required-syncfusion-angular-components-to-reduce-bundle-size

Comment: HI Karthick,  
Can we do the same for theme and css too? As still i can see the Syncfusion css is occupying about 1 MB of space in vendor.js file. Do we have a technique using which we can import css specific to grid only. Thanks

Comment: @programoholic : You can use the themestudio to generate theme for specific component. https://js.syncfusion.com/themestudio/ . Refer the downloaded file in your application.